# How to restrict access to Identity Toolkit API?

Tags: firebase, next.js, postman

I have a Next.js website with firebase. It takes care of everything I need with authentication. However, In addition to the signInWithPopup, I am also using signInWithEmailAndPassword function in order to let my users authenticate using email and password.

The problem is that signInWithEmailAndPassword sends a request to:

```
https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=[PUBLIC_KEY]
```

And it returns a valid response with the authToken. And when I paste the request in Postman, I see that everyone can access this endpoint. How can I protect this route? I want this route to be accessible just from my website.

I saw that there is something called App-Check that can restrict access to API but couldn't find a way to make it work.

Thank you!

Comment: Firebase App Check is currently not yet available for Firebase Authentication or Google Cloud Identity Platform. Aside from that, this is probably a good place to start: https://developers.google.com/maps/api-security-best-practices#application-restriction

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This protection is for Google Maps API - I couldn't find the page for the IdentityToolkit API. Could you assist?